# What do you mean by "hand-tipped"?

Tags: meaning

In the movie You've Got Mail, George shows Joe a first edition of Swiss Family Robinson in Kathleen's bookstore and says "The illustrations are hand-tipped, which is why --", and Joe says "It costs so much."
Does it mean "hand-crafted"?

Answer (score 4):

As a former librarian, I can answer this. It means that the illustrations were printed separately, probably on special [art paper](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/art-paper) and glued into the book by hand. Before modern  methods of colour printing, it was not possible to print high-quality coloured pictures on the same page as text.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipped-in_page

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it essentially means *hand-crafted*.

It's an unusual expression.

However, from [**tip**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip#h3):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *noun (2)*
>   **1** : the usually pointed end of something
>       // a pencil *tip*

In this sense, it's a verbification of that noun.

Since it's talking about an illustration, the more common verbal phrase would be [**hand-drawn**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hand-drawn):

> [Lexico (Oxford)]
>   **2.** Of an image: drawn by hand, as opposed to having been created by photography or computer software; specifically (of the soundtrack to a film) created by hand-drawing sound waves directly on to the celluloid, as opposed to by recording using a microphone.

The reason it costs so much is because, generally speaking, human labour is more expensive than mechanical reproduction.

Answer (score 1):

It's when they've printed the image separately from the book (on paper that better handles images), and then they glue the image in.

Here's a pic where you can see one:

http://thebookblog.com/uploads/jekyllhyde8.jpg